How to add IPv6 addresses more than 1024 IP with netplan
I have a problem with netplan. I do my http proxy server with ipv6 project, and I need to add more addresses in file /etc/netplan/some_config.yaml all config no error, but when I add IP more than 1024 IP address. 1025-5000 IP not adding to ip a It only shows 1024 IP. When I checked the syslog file I got this error.

